# Devise in rails giving error on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I am using devise with mongoid. App has two devise models users and investors. When I sign-up for each in localhost it works fine but on heroku when I submit form the page get redirects to app/users or app/investors and I got 500 service internal error. In the app the views directory of users and investors are separately defined. 
Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue was the mongodb service, they actually reset the password, so I have to change that in mongoid.yml. My advice for people working with service:

1) Start your debugging with config files the username and password before jumping to plugin code. I spend 5 hours in debugging devise internal code and problem was somewhere else.